# AWS SDK - How to set the VPC name tag using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc

How can I specify the VPC name tag using the AWS SDK when creating vpc? I tried a number of options as shown here but no success.

Here is how I create my VPC using python, boto3 SDK.

```
import os
import boto3
import time    
....
....
print('Creating VPC')
# Create new VPC environment
vpc = client.create_vpc(CidrBlock='10.0.0.0/16', InstanceTenancy='default')
client.modify_vpc_attribute(VpcId=vpc['Vpc']['VpcId'], EnableDnsSupport={'Value': True})
client.modify_vpc_attribute(VpcId=vpc['Vpc']['VpcId'], EnableDnsHostnames={'Value': True})
```

Currently, it creates the vpc without a name tag.

I tried specifying the tag either during creating vpc or when I am modifying it as shown below but none of the options work.

```
vpc = client.create_vpc(CidrBlock='10.0.0.0/16', InstanceTenancy='default', Tags="myvpcnametag")
client.modify_vpc_attribute(VpcId=vpc['Vpc']['VpcId'], Tags="myvpctag")
```

Comment: Try vpc.create_tags(Tags=[{"Key": "Name", "Value": "myvpctag"}])

Comment: @jarmod. I am sure your code is correct as well, but I was missing the resource. Upvoting your comment. tx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work if you have the VPC id:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
client.create_tags(Resources=['vpc-78a54011'], Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'MyVPC'}])
```

Here is how I modified it and worked great.

## Create new VPC environment

```
vpc = client.create_vpc(CidrBlock='10.0.0.0/16', InstanceTenancy='default')

client.modify_vpc_attribute(VpcId=vpc['Vpc']['VpcId'], EnableDnsSupport={'Value': True})
client.modify_vpc_attribute(VpcId=vpc['Vpc']['VpcId'], EnableDnsHostnames={'Value': True})

client.create_tags(Resources=[vpc['Vpc']['VpcId']], Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'DariusVPC'}])
```

Comment: I had to modify the code to get the VPC id dynamically and it worked nicely.

Comment: @Stryker how do you get the vpc id dynamically?